# Jquery - sorting table data after load

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table

I'd like to order the data that is shown in my table. So entries 'sit' beneath there correct section.

I'm retrieving data from a database AD via LDAP. This is then being presented to the screen in a table like so..

```
<tr id="MAIN:1" class="group_heading nodrag"><td colspan="4">MAIN1</td></tr>

<tr id="1" class="toggler_row" data-group="S:1" style="cursor: move;">
    <td><input name="local[]" type="text" value="54-A944"></td>
    <td><input name="description[]" type="text" value="MidWest"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="8" class="toggler_row" data-group="S:2" style="cursor: move;">
    <td><input name="local[]" type="text" value="16-B120"></td>
    <td><input name="description[]" type="text" value="SouthEast"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="2" class="toggler_row" data-group="" style="cursor: move;">
    <td><input name="local[]" type="text" value="12-B879"></td>
    <td><input name="description[]" type="text" value="South"></td>
</tr>


<tr id="MAIN:2" class="group_heading nodrag"><td colspan="4">MAIN2</td></tr>

<tr id="6" class="toggler_row" data-group="S:2" style="cursor: move;">
    <td><input name="local[]" type="text" value="79-C878"></td>
    <td><input name="description[]" type="text" value="LOCAL"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="5" class="toggler_row" data-group="S:1" style="cursor: move;">
    <td><input name="local[]" type="text" value="82-A942"></td>
    <td><input name="description[]" type="text" value="SouthWest"></td>
</tr>
```

The section `header` entries are similar to this :

```
<tr id="MAIN:1" class="group_heading nodrag"><td colspan="4">MAIN1</td></tr>
```

They have an ID starting `MAIN` followed by the section number eg 1

The entries that should sit under this section have a data-group of `S:1`  so any S:1 should be beneath MAIN:1

Any S:2 beneath MAIN:2 and so on.. any entry with no data-group should be under a section with the ID `NONE`

How do I loop through the table entries and move them to the correct location ?

There may be many MAIN sections and possible lots of sub entries.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I've got this working using:

```
$("tr.toggler_row").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    var group = $(this).data('group');
    var arr = group.split(':');
    if (arr[1]) {
        $('#' + id).insertAfter('#MAIN\\:' + arr[1]);
    } else {
        $('#' + id).insertAfter('#NONE');
    }
});
```

This is being called once the page has loaded and seems to work OK.
is there a better way than that ?

Thanks

Comment: Like this? https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Comment: very much like that, but I don't want to use datatables in this case.
Any way to do it with out that ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding I think this is what you are looking for. Click on Sort button for sorting table rows.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getAttributesString(element) {
     var AttrString = "";
     $.each(element.attributes, function() {
         if(this.specified) {
          AttrString += " " + this.name + "='" + this.value + "' ";
         }
     });
     return AttrString;
  }
  
  function getRowHTML(element){
      var html = "";
    html += '<tr ' + getAttributesString(element) + ' >';
      html += $(element).html();
      html += "</tr>";
      return html;
  }
  
  $("#Sort").click(function(){
      var sortedHtml = "";
      sortedHtml += "<table>";
      $("table tr[id^='MAIN:']").each(function(){     
        sortedHtml += getRowHTML(this);
          var headerId =  this.id.split(':')[1];
          if (headerId != "") {
            $("table tr[data-group='S:" + headerId + "']").each(function(){
                 sortedHtml += getRowHTML(this);
            });
          }
          else {
            $("table tr[data-group='']").each(function(){
                sortedHtml += getRowHTML(this);
            });
          }
      });
      sortedHtml += "</table>";
      $("#container").html("");
      $("#container").html(sortedHtml);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<table>
<tr id="MAIN:1" class="group_heading nodrag"><td colspan="4">MAIN1</td></tr>

<tr id="1" class="toggler_row" data-group="S:1" style="cursor: move;">
    <td><input name="local[]" type="text" value="54-A944"></td>
    <td><input name="description[]" type="text" value="MidWest"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="8" class="toggler_row" data-group="S:2" style="cursor: move;">
    <td><input name="local[]" type="text" value="16-B120"></td>
    <td><input name="description[]" type="text" value="SouthEast"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="2" class="toggler_row" data-group="" style="cursor: move;">
    <td><input name="local[]" type="text" value="12-B879"></td>
    <td><input name="description[]" type="text" value="South"></td>
</tr>


<tr id="MAIN:2" class="group_heading nodrag"><td colspan="4">MAIN2</td></tr>

<tr id="6" class="toggler_row" data-group="S:2" style="cursor: move;">
    <td><input name="local[]" type="text" value="79-C878"></td>
    <td><input name="description[]" type="text" value="LOCAL"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="5" class="toggler_row" data-group="S:1" style="cursor: move;">
    <td><input name="local[]" type="text" value="82-A942"></td>
    <td><input name="description[]" type="text" value="SouthWest"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="MAIN:" class="group_heading nodrag"><td colspan="4">Others</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" id="Sort"> Sort </button>
```

**[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/79/)**

Comment: thanks that does do what I need, I've just updated my question with a way I found and that also seems to work.